# Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'BlogPost'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am using **Typescript with NextJS** I am getting the below mentioned Typescript error on both my **api.tsx and blogPost.tsx** files:

> Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'BlogPost'.ts(2451) api.tsx(3,
>   7): 'BlogPost' was also declared here.

Also I am getting this error on my **blogPost.tsx** file

> All files must be modules when the '--isolatedModules' flag is
>   provided.

Here is my code:

**blogPost.tsx**

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const BlogPostSchema = new Schema({
title: String,
body: String,
date: {
    type: String,
    default: Date.now()
}
 });

const BlogPost = mongoose.model('BlogPost', BlogPostSchema); //error on this line
```

**api.tsx**

```
const express= require('express');
const router=express.Router();
const BlogPost=require('../models/blogPost');


//Routes

router.get('/api', (req, res) => {


    BlogPost.find({ })
    .then((data)=> {
        console.log('Data:', data);
        res.json(data);
    })

    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log('error:');
    });

    // res.json(data);

    });

   router.get('/api/name', (req, res) => {
    const data = {
        username: 'caa',
        age: 5
    };
    res.json(data);

    });

module.exports=router;
```

Comment: try `module.export = mongoose.model('BlogPost', BlogPostSchema);` in `blogPost.tsx`

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when TS is not recognise your files as modules.
It define a file as a module when it uses `import` / `export` syntax.

Try to change it to use `import` / `export` syntax.

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const BlogPostSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  body: String,
  date: {
    type: String,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
});

export const BlogPost = mongoose.model('BlogPost', BlogPostSchema);
```

```
import express from 'express';
import { BlogPost } from '../models/blogPost';

export const router = express.Router();

//Routes

router.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  BlogPost.find({})
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Data:', data);
      res.json(data);
    })

    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error:');
    });

  // res.json(data);
});

router.get('/api/name', (req, res) => {
  const data = {
    username: 'caa',
    age: 5,
  };
  res.json(data);
});
```